# Appengine forms Option Select from db.Model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

My application does not write all data in the database. In the example below just type in the DB name. All fields select dropdown are not recorded in the database. Help please

**I have a models Docente**

```
ESCOLHA_SEXO = (u'masculino', u'feminino')
CHOICES_UNIDADE = ('Escola Superior de Tecnologia', 'Escola Superior de Gestao') 
CHOICES_CATEGORIA = ('assistente', 'coordenador', 'adjunto')
CHOICES_REGIME = ('trinta', 'cinquenta', 'sessenta', 'cem')

class Docente(db.Model):
    photo=db.BlobProperty(u'photo')
    docente_nome = db.StringProperty(u'docente_nome', 
                                     required=False)
    docente_unidade = db.StringProperty(u'docente_unidade', 
                                        required=False, 
                                        default='Escola Superior de Tecnologia', 
                                        choices = CHOICES_UNIDADE )
    docente_categoria = db.StringProperty(u'docente_categoria', 
                                          default='assistente', 
                                          choices =CHOICES_CATEGORIA)
    docente_regime = db.StringProperty(u'docente_regime', 
                                       required=False, 
                                       choices =CHOICES_REGIME)
    utilizador=db.ReferenceProperty(Utilizador, 
                                    verbose_name=u'utilizador', 
                                    required=False, 
                                    collection_name='utilizadores')
```

**This is my main:**

```
class CriarCvHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        if self.request.get('EscDocente'):
            id = int(self.request.get('EscDocente'))
            docente=models.Docente.get(db.Key.from_path('Docente', id))
        else:
            docente = models.Docente()

        data=forms.DocenteForm(data = self.request.POST)
        if data.is_valid():
            if self.request.get('photo'):
                docente.docente_nome=self.request.get('docente_nome')
                docente.docente_unidade=self.request.get('docente_unidade')
                docente.docente_categoria=self.request.get('docente_categoria')
                docente.docente_regime=self.request.get('docente_regime')

            listaUtlz = models.Utilizador.all()
            listaUtlz.filter('user =', users.get_current_user())

            for utilizador in listaUtlz:
                docente.utilizador=utilizador.key()

            docente.put()
            self.redirect('/academia')
        else:
            self.redirect('/criarCv')

    def get(self):
        user=users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            greeting= ("<ul><li><strong><b>Benvindo %s </b></strong>|</li><li><a href=\"/perfil\"> Minha Conta </a>|</li><li><a href=\"%s\"> Logout</a></li></ul>" %(user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url("/")))
        else:
            greeting = ("<ul><li><a href=\"%s\">Login</a></li></ul>" %(users.create_login_url("/")))

        conjUnidade=models.Docente.docente_unidade.choices
        conjCategoria=models.Docente.docente_categoria.choices
        conjRegime=models.Docente.docente_regime.choices

        utilizador=db.Query(models.Utilizador)
        utilizador=utilizador.filter('user =', user)
        listaUtlz=utilizador.fetch(limit=1)

        if self.request.GET.has_key('id'):
            id=int(self.request.GET['id'])
            EscDocente=models.Docente.get(db.Key.from_path('Docente', id))

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/criarCv.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, locals(), debug = True))
```

**This is my template:**
      Nome Docente:

```
<tr>
  <td>Unidade: </td>
  <td>
    <select name="docente_unidade">
      {% for docente_unidade in conjUnidade  %}
        <option selected> {{ docente_unidade }} </option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Categoria: </td>
  <td>
    <select name="categoria">
      <option></option>
        {% for docente_categoria in conjCategoria  %}
          {% ifequal EscDocente.docente_categoria docente_categoria %}
            <option selected> {{ docente_categoria }} </option>
          {% else %}
            <option> {{ docente_categoria }} </option>
          {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<td>Regime: </td>
  <td>
    <select name="regime">
      <option></option>
        {% for docente_regime in conjRegime  %}
          {% ifequal EscDocente.docente_regime docente_regime %}
            <option selected> {{ docente_regime }} </option>
          {% else %}
            <option> {{ docente_regime }} </option>
          {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </td>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Guardar" onclick="guardaCv()" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think some of your template wasn't included.  Please, in the future, use the code formatting button or ctrl-k.

Answer (score 1):

**Change these**:

```
<select name="categoria">
```

...

```
<select name="regime">
```

**To this**:

```
<select name="docente_categoria">
```

...

```
<select name="docente_regime">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bernier.
This little problem is already fixed, but i have another, which i have posted.
I have 5 model entities and need to Fill a Form on the same page with different classes - write to DB and display values